# How to write popup in kv file when one press button

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.factory import Factory

class My3App(App):
    def build(self):
        return Hello()


class Hello(Widget):
    def btn(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    My3App().run()



kv File

<Hello>:
    Button:
        text : "button1"
        on_press : root.btn()
```

How do I create a Popup when I click on button1? I want a large popup which contains so many buttons and labels. How do I write that popup in kv language?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Question 1

How do I create a Popup when I click on button1?

### Solution

In this solution, it illustrates the use of [dynamic class](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#dynamic-classes), and it involves changing both kv file and Python script.

#### kv file

- Add import statement of Kivy `Factory`
- Add a dynamic class, `CustomPopup` with inheritance of `Popup` widget
- Add `on_release` event for button1 which use Kivy `Factory` to register and instantiate dynamic class, `CustomPopup`. Use Popup's `open()` method to display the Popup's window.

Snippets - kv

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
...
<CustomPopup@Popup>:
...
<Hello>:
    Button:
        text : "button1"
        on_release: Factory.CustomPopup().open()
```

#### Py file

- Remove `btn()` method from `class Hello()`
- Add `pass` to `class Hello()`

Snippets - Py

```
class Hello(Widget):
    pass
```

## Question 2

How do I write that popup in kv language?

### Solution

There are two methods to implementing a class with Popup inheritance.

#### Method 1 - Using [Dynamic Class](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#dynamic-classes)

In this method, it involves changes to only kv file. We added a dynamic class rule.

Snippets - kv

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<CustomPopup@Popup>:
    title: 'Test popup'
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (400, 400)
    Label:
        text: 'Hello world'

<Hello>:
    Button:
        text : "button1"
        on_release: Factory.CustomPopup().open()
```

#### Method 2 - Using Normal Class

In this method, it involves changes to both kv file and Python script. We added a class rule in kv file, and implement a class in Python script.

Snippets - kv

```
<CustomPopup>:
    title: 'Test popup'
    size_hint: (None, None)
    size: (400, 400)
    Label:
        text: 'Hello world'

<Hello>:
    Button:
        text : "button1"
        on_press: root.btn()
```

Snippets - Py

```
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
...
class CustomPopup(Popup):
    pass


class Hello(Widget):
    def btn(self):
        popup = CustomPopup()
        popup.open()
```

## Question 3

I want a large popup which contains so many buttons and labels.

### Solution

In this solution, we will be using [dynamic class](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#dynamic-classes), and add buttons and labels into kv file. When creating a popup, you must at least set a [Popup.title](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.popup.html#kivy.uix.popup.Popup.title) and [Popup.content](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.popup.html#kivy.uix.popup.Popup.content). The `Popup.content` can be any widget e.g. [Screen](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen), [Layouts](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/layouts.html) ([BoxLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html), [GridLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html), etc), [Label](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html), [Button](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html), etc. With a [BoxLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html) or [GridLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html), you can add [Label](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html), and [Button](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html).

#### Snippets - kv

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<CustomPopup@Popup>:
    title: 'My Custom Kivy Popup'
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 0.9
            Label:
                text: 'Hello'
            Label:
                text: 'Kivy'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                text: 'Linux'
            Label:
                text: 'Python'

        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            row_force_default: True
            row_default_height: '46dp'
            col_force_default: True
            col_default_width: '200dp'
            Button:
                text: 'Close this popup'
                on_release: root.dismiss()
            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                on_release: root.dismiss()

<Hello>:
    Button:
        text : "button1"
        on_release: Factory.CustomPopup().open()
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out...it is working .....Now I understand this is the use of Factory class...

Answer (score -2):

you should check this tutorial: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.popup.html

```
MyPopup = Popup(title='Test popup', content=Label(text='Hello world'),
          auto_dismiss=False
Button:
    text: 'Open popup'
    on_release: Factory.MyPopup().open()
```

Comment: i have edited my reply to contain a piece of code. try it

Comment: Basicly when I click the 'open popup' button , then with the help of Factory I am going to Mypop class which contain popup...